# SQL show difference of two tables and compare the result to another table with different database

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my dbtest1 structure

Database name: `dbtest1`

Table `tbl1`

```
id | name  | age
1  | johny | 26
2  | jane  | 25
3  | mike  | 32
4  | jean  | 33
```

Table `tbl2`

```
id | name | age
1  | john | 26
2  | jane | 25
3  | mike | 42
```

using this query below to get the difference of the two table.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT *, 'tableT1' AS fromTable FROM tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 'tableT2' AS fromTable FROM tbl2
) tbl
GROUP BY id, name, age
HAVING count(*) = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

I get this result.

```
id | name | age | fromTable
1  | john | 26  | tableT1
3  | mike | 42  | tableT2
4  | jean | 33  | tableT1
```

Now my problem is how can I able to compare the above result to `dbtest2`?I have no idea how to implement this..thanks in advance.

---

Database name: `dbtest2`

Table `tbl3`

```
id | name | age
1  | john | 26
2  | jane | 25
3  | mike | 42
```

Comment: Assuming the user has the same privileges then it's just another UNION. add the database reference to the table name, e.g. `dbtest2.tbl3`

Answer (score 1):

You can use fully qualified names. They are generally have the following syntax:

```
DATABASE_NAME.TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME
```

Where each of the identifiers separated with `.` is the name of their namespaces. When you are issuing a query that is in current namespace, you can omit the name of the namespace, like you say `desc tbl3` when you are in `dbtest2`.

Here is how you would do it in your query:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM (
     SELECT *, 'tableT1' AS fromTable FROM tbl1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT *, 'tableT2' AS fromTable FROM tbl2
     UNION ALL
     SELECT *, 'tableT3' AS fromTable FROM dbtest2.tbl3 # Here use fully qualified table name
 ) tbl
 GROUP BY id, name, age
 HAVING count(*) = 1
 ORDER BY id;
```